# HTML Purifier module and upload YouTube videos not working

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

I am using the HTML Purifier module https://www.drupal.org/project/htmlpurifier. And Drupal version 8.5.6. Most of the help I could find is for Drupal version 7. When I try to embed a YouTube video into the Ckeditor the iframe tag remains but the src url is stripped out. I am allowing every element and class like this, this is part of my GUI config for html purifier:

```
HTML:
 Allowed: null
 AllowedAttributes: null
 AllowedElements: null
 SafeEmbed: true
 SafeIframe: true
 SafeObject: true
 FlashCompat: false
 SafeIframeRegexp: null
 YouTube: true
```

And below is the full config file.

```
        Attr:
      AllowedClasses: null
      AllowedFrameTargets: _blank,_self,_target,_parent
      AllowedRel: {  }
      AllowedRev: {  }
      ClassUseCDATA: null
      DefaultImageAlt: null
      DefaultInvalidImage: ''
      DefaultInvalidImageAlt: 'Invalid image'
      DefaultTextDir: ltr
      EnableID: false
      ForbiddenClasses: myHeader2,myHeader3,mso*,mso-*
      ID.HTML5: null
      IDBlacklist: {  }
      IDBlacklistRegexp: null
      IDPrefix: ''
      IDPrefixLocal: ''
    AutoFormat:
      AutoParagraph: false
      Custom: {  }
      DisplayLinkURI: false
      Linkify: false
      PurifierLinkify.DocURL: '#%s'
      PurifierLinkify: false
      RemoveEmpty.Predicate:
        colgroup: {  }
        th: {  }
        td: {  }
        iframe:
          - src
      RemoveEmpty.RemoveNbsp.Exceptions:
        td: true
        th: true
      RemoveEmpty.RemoveNbsp: false
      RemoveEmpty: false
      RemoveSpansWithoutAttributes: false
    CSS:
      AllowDuplicates: true
      AllowImportant: true
      AllowTricky: false
      AllowedFonts: null
      AllowedProperties: null
      DefinitionRev: 1
      ForbiddenProperties: {  }
      MaxImgLength: 1200px
      Proprietary: true
      Trusted: true
    Cache:
      DefinitionImpl: Serializer
      SerializerPath: null
      SerializerPermissions: 493
    Core:
      AggressivelyFixLt: true
      AggressivelyRemoveScript: true
      AllowHostnameUnderscore: false
      CollectErrors: false
      ColorKeywords:
        maroon: '#800000'
        red: '#FF0000'
        orange: '#FFA500'
        yellow: '#FFFF00'
        olive: '#808000'
        purple: '#800080'
        fuchsia: '#FF00FF'
        white: '#FFFFFF'
        lime: '#00FF00'
        green: '#008000'
        navy: '#000080'
        blue: '#0000FF'
        aqua: '#00FFFF'
        teal: '#008080'
        black: '#000000'
        silver: '#C0C0C0'
        gray: '#808080'
      ConvertDocumentToFragment: true
      DirectLexLineNumberSyncInterval: 0
      DisableExcludes: false
      EnableIDNA: false
      Encoding: utf-8
      EscapeInvalidChildren: false
      EscapeInvalidTags: false
      EscapeNonASCIICharacters: false
      HiddenElements:
        script: true
        style: true
      Language: en
      LegacyEntityDecoder: false
      LexerImpl: null
      MaintainLineNumbers: null
      NormalizeNewlines: true
      RemoveInvalidImg: true
      RemoveProcessingInstructions: false
      RemoveScriptContents: null
    Filter:
      Custom: {  }
      ExtractStyleBlocks.Escaping: true
      ExtractStyleBlocks.Scope: null
      ExtractStyleBlocks.TidyImpl: null
      ExtractStyleBlocks: false
      YouTube: true
    HTML:
      Allowed: null
      AllowedAttributes: null
      AllowedComments: {  }
      AllowedCommentsRegexp: null
      AllowedElements: null
      AllowedModules: null
      Attr.Name.UseCDATA: false
      BlockWrapper: p
      CoreModules:
        Structure: true
        Text: true
        Hypertext: true
        List: true
        NonXMLCommonAttributes: true
        XMLCommonAttributes: true
        CommonAttributes: true
      CustomDoctype: null
      DefinitionID: null
      DefinitionRev: 1
      Doctype: null
      FlashAllowFullScreen: true
      ForbiddenAttributes: {  }
      ForbiddenElements: s,h2,h3
      MaxImgLength: 1200
      Nofollow: false
      Parent: div
      Proprietary: true
      SafeEmbed: true
      SafeIframe: true
      SafeObject: true
      SafeScripting: {  }
      Strict: false
      TargetBlank: true
      TargetNoopener: true
      TargetNoreferrer: true
      TidyAdd: {  }
      TidyLevel: medium
      TidyRemove: {  }
      Trusted: true
      XHTML: true
    Output:
      CommentScriptContents: true
      FixInnerHTML: false
      FlashCompat: false
      Newline: null
      SortAttr: false
      TidyFormat: false
    Test:
      ForceNoIconv: false
    URI:
      AllowedSchemes:
        http: true
        https: true
        mailto: true
        ftp: true
        nntp: true
        news: true
        tel: true
      Base: null
      DefaultScheme: http
      DefinitionID: null
      DefinitionRev: 1
      Disable: false
      DisableExternal: false
      DisableExternalResources: false
      DisableResources: false
      Host: null
      HostBlacklist: {  }
      MakeAbsolute: false
      Munge: null
      MungeResources: false
      MungeSecretKey: null
      OverrideAllowedSchemes: false
      SafeIframeRegexp: null
```

Answer (score 1):

It works now after changing the last setting in the config file to this:
SafeIframeRegexp: %(www.youtube.com/embed)%